# Test Flight sessions are empty

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I upload builds to testflightapp.com for testers. Some of my sessions don't have logs inside, only start time and no finish time. Either there are no crash logs, so as I suppose crashes are not relative to this issue. I don't have problems with the most part of sessions, only with some. Why this could happen ?

Comment: By *logs* do you mean checkpoints? Are you sure the **[TestFlight takeOff:YOUR_TEAM_ID]** method is called? Do you test on many different devices? Maybe the problem is device/os specific?

Comment: No, by logs I mean TFlogs, on the same device some sessions are empty and some are not.

Answer (score 1):

For more accurate logs of their builds, you must implement the testing framework that you can find the link:

https://testflightapp.com/sdk/

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the mentioned tutorials in the homepage?

http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/topics/184165-tutorials/articles

Answer (score 0):

Sessions(As described on https://testflightapp.com/sdk/)：
Discover how testers are using your application. Watch as they progress and take unexpected turns.

None crash log:
It maybe you are using some third part analytics tools such as [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/flurry-analytics.html). 
These tools owns the Unexception-handler. You could config your TestFlight SDK to force owns the Unexception-handler in your AppDelegate using below codes

```
NSString *udid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
[TestFlight setDeviceIdentifier:udid];

[TestFlight takeOff:@"YOUR TESTFLIGHT SECRET KEY"];

[TestFlight setOptions:@{TFOptionReinstallCrashHandlers : @YES}];
```